# Swift - Make defined range of a text field editable

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have a text field and would like to make a part of it editable (not the whole text field).

I tried out something like the code below, to make only the first 6 characters of the text field editable. However, without any success.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextView!

textField.editable(NSRange(location: 0, length: 6)) = true
```

Does anyone know to solve this issue?

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1):

let user enter only 6 char and digits , I have been using this..!!
use this function in your view controller

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    var result = true
    let prospectiveText = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    if textField == textField {
        if count(string) > 0 {
            let disallowedCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "0123456789").invertedSet
            let replacementStringIsLegal = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(disallowedCharacterSet) == nil

            let resultingStringLengthIsLegal = count(prospectiveText) <= 6

            let scanner = NSScanner(string: prospectiveText)
            let resultingTextIsNumeric = scanner.scanDecimal(nil) && scanner.atEnd

            result = replacementStringIsLegal &&
                resultingStringLengthIsLegal &&
            resultingTextIsNumeric
        }


    }
    return result
}
```

and put this in viewDidAppear

```
textField.delegate = self
```

and inherit

```
class YourClassName: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

hope this code will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply, Irshad Qureshi!

I tried out your code and it works perfectly fine. However, I am intending to create a program, where the user sees a text that he has to complete. For example: A typical characteristic of _____ is their long neck. (answer: giraffs)

So the user should be able to tap on the ____ and edit only this part.

Please excuse, if my first post was misleading. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you..??

Answer (score -1):

How about two side by side or overlapping text fields? One could be editable, the other not. You could adjust borders to make it look seamless.

[image]

Comment: not sure why this was down voted. I've added a picture that does exactly what you're describing with two fields. In one field, it is either all editable or all not editable. What you're looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: Moreover, on your other, nearly identical question, this same suggestion was made to you by @TheCodingArt.